# Bootstrap 3 Form Wizard

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-wizard

Hi I am having problem with the form wizard I am using for bootstrap 3.0.3

It's actually working but the next and previous buttons are not but when I click on the navigation it's working.

I don't know if the versions are compatible I downloaded this plugin

https://github.com/VinceG/twitter-bootstrap-wizard

But it says on the documentation is it compatible with 3.0.3

Any suggestions that is working for the bootstrap 3.0.3 form wizard?

Thank you. Your comments are high appreciated :)

[image: here's the screenshot]

this is my html code

```
<div class="row">
        <div id="rootwizard">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab"><span class="label">1</span> First</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab"><span class="label">2</span> Second</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab"><span class="label">3</span> Third</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tab4" data-toggle="tab"><span class="label">4</span> Forth</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tab5" data-toggle="tab"><span class="label">5</span> Fifth</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tab6" data-toggle="tab"><span class="label">6</span> Sixth</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tab7" data-toggle="tab"><span class="label">7</span> Seventh</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane" id="tab1">
                  1
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
                  2
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
                    3
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="tab4">
                    4
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="tab5">
                    5
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="tab6">
                    6
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="tab7">
                    7
                </div>
                <ul class="pager wizard">
                    <li class="previous first" style="display:none;"><a href="#">First</a></li>
                    <li class="previous"><a href="#">Previous</a></li>
                    <li class="next last" style="display:none;"><a href="#">Last</a></li>
                    <li class="next"><a href="#">Next</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is my CSS

```
.bwizard-steps {
display: inline-block;
margin: 0; padding: 0;
background: #fff }
.bwizard-steps .active {
    color: #fff;
    background: #007ACC }
.bwizard-steps .active:after {
    border-left-color: #007ACC }
.bwizard-steps .active a {
    color: #fff;
    cursor: default }
.bwizard-steps .label {
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;
    margin: 0 5px 0 0; padding: 1px 5px 2px }
.bwizard-steps .active .label {
    background-color: #333;}
.bwizard-steps li {
    display: inline-block; position: relative;
    margin-right: 5px;
    padding: 12px 17px 10px 30px;
    *display: inline;
    *padding-left: 17px;
    background: #efefef;
    line-height: 18px;
    list-style: none;
    zoom: 1; }
.bwizard-steps li:first-child {
    padding-left: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
    border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px; }
.bwizard-steps li:first-child:before {
    border: none }
.bwizard-steps li:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
    border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0; }
.bwizard-steps li:last-child:after {
    border: none }
.bwizard-steps li:before {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; top: 0;
    height: 0; width: 0;
    border-bottom: 20px inset transparent;
    border-left: 20px solid #fff;
    border-top: 20px inset transparent;
    content: "" }
.bwizard-steps li:after {
    position: absolute;
    right: -20px; top: 0;
    height: 0; width: 0;
    border-bottom: 20px inset transparent;
    border-left: 20px solid #efefef;
    border-top: 20px inset transparent;
    content: "";
    z-index: 2; }
.bwizard-steps a {
    color: #333 }
.bwizard-steps a:hover {
    text-decoration: none }
     .bwizard-steps.clickable li:not(.active) {
cursor: pointer }
    .bwizard-steps.clickable li:hover:not(.active) {
background: #ccc }
    .bwizard-steps.clickable li:hover:not(.active):after {
border-left-color: #ccc }
    .bwizard-steps.clickable li:hover:not(.active) a {
color: #08c }
    @media (max-width: 480px) { 
/* badges only on small screens */
.bwizard-steps li:after,
.bwizard-steps li:before {
    border: none }
.bwizard-steps li,
.bwizard-steps li.active,
.bwizard-steps li:first-child,
.bwizard-steps li:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: transparent }
     }
```

And this is my JS

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#rootwizard').bootstrapWizard({'tabClass': 'bwizard-steps'});    
    window.prettyPrint && prettyPrint()
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this issue.

It is not supporting 3.0.3.

It is working fine in bootstrap 2.x versions.

I cannot change version to 2 so I used jQuery:

```
$('#nextTab').click(function(){
 $('#navTab').find('.active').next().children().trigger('click');
})

$('#prevTab').click(function(){
  $('#navTab').find('.active').prev().children().trigger('click');
})
```

You can add or remove classes for better look and feel.

Answer (score 1):

From [github](https://github.com/VinceG/twitter-bootstrap-wizard)

> We will not longer be updating the bower version of bootstrap wizard
>   or any other package manager. See #81 for the reason why. Please use
>   'master' branch instead.

use `bower install twitter-bootstrap-wizard#master`

Answer (score 1):

`bower` is not updated for 
`bootsrtap 3.x`, instead download zip from 
[github](https://github.com/VinceG/twitter-bootstrap-wizard) and it should be good to go with `bootstrap 3.x`

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too. The version of bootstrap wizard bundled with revox.io was incompatible with the version of bootstrap. See https://github.com/VinceG/twitter-bootstrap-wizard for up to date versions.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is because of incompatibility of bootstrap Javascript with the bootstrap wizard's javascript. 
I tried bootstrap Javascript version 2.3.2. The back and next button started working.

I have written a article explaining solution to this issue here

http://codezag.com/bootstrap-wizard-next-button-not-working/